# Creating a grid from an array of <div>'s

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to write a simple function that accepts an array of items, then returns that array in nested divs.

What I have so far:

```
// items that need to be nested
$arr_items = array('<div>A</div>','<div>B</div>','<div>C</div>','<div>D</div>','<div>E</div>','<div>F</div>','<div>G</div>','<div>H</div>','<div>I</div>','<div>J</div>','<div>K</div>','<div>L</div>');

// build columns of items
$cols_per_row   = 2;
$cols_last      = $cols_per_row + 1;
$column_group_open  = "\n<div class='columns'>\n";
$column_group_close = "</div>\n";
$c_items = count($arr_items);

if ($c_items>0)
{
    $html = $column_group_open;
    $c=0;
    foreach ($arr_items as $item)
    {
        // add item to current colun
        $html .= $item;
        if ($c==$cols_per_row)
        {
            // end current column 
            $html .= $column_group_close;

            // are there more items left?
            if ($c<$c_items)
            {
                // start another column
                $html .= $column_group_open;
            }
        }

        $c++;
    }
    // close last column
    if ($c<$cols_last) {$html .= $column_group_close;}

}
```

Clearly something is off.  Current output:

```
<div class='columns'>
<div>A</div><div>B</div><div>C</div></div>

<div class='columns'>
<div>D</div><div>E</div><div>F</div><div>G</div><div>H</div><div>I</div><div>J</div><div>K</div><div>L</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class='columns'>
<div>A</div><div>B</div></div>

<div class='columns'>
<div>C</div><div>D</div></div>

<div class='columns'>
<div>E</div><div>F</div></div>

<div class='columns'>
<div>G</div><div>H</div></div>

<div class='columns'>
<div>I</div><div>J</div></div>

<div class='columns'>
<div>L</div></div>
```

Am I *way* off the mark with my example code?  What do I need to check or amend to get this working?  Or is there an existing library I could use?

Comment: Instead of `if ($c==$cols_per_row)` try `if ($c > 0 && $c % $cols_per_row == 0)`. I think the two problems are: array keys start at zero so the first time `$c` is `2` is on the *third* not *second* element; and after that `$c` is always greater than `$cols_per_row`. The `%` operator returns you the remainder after dividing `$c` by `$cols_per_row`.

Comment: This is closer, though the first group contains 3 divs (the rest of the groups contain 2, except for the last with 1 which is expected)

Comment: Oh yeah, fair point. `if ($c % $cols_per_row = $cols_per_row - 1)`?

Comment: Had to add back the `$c>0` clause, then this works OK:  `if ($c>0 && $c%$cols_per_row == $cols_per_row - 1)`.  Feel free to drop this answer for the hookup.

Comment: I wish @MattRaines would post his as an answer, it's the one I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%` operator to get the remainder after dividing `$c` by `$cols_per_row` to close the row whenever `$cols_per_row` columns have been added.

ie `if ($c > 0 && $c % $cols_per_row == $cols_per_row - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without any loops, using some of PHP's built-in array manipulation functions:

```
$arr_items    = [
    '<div>A</div>', '<div>B</div>', '<div>C</div>', '<div>D</div>', '<div>E</div>', '<div>F</div>',
    '<div>G</div>', '<div>H</div>', '<div>I</div>', '<div>J</div>', '<div>K</div>', '<div>L</div>'
];
$cols_per_row = 2;
$cg_open      = "\n<div class='columns'>\n";
$cg_close     = "\n</div>\n";

$result  = array_chunk($arr_items, $cols_per_row);
$result2 = array_map(
    function($i) use ($cg_open, $cg_close) {return $cg_open . implode("", $i)  .$cg_close;},
    $result
);
echo implode("\n", $result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified.

Please check the following. You will may need to remove the PHP_EOL bits in order to have syntactically correct HTML.

```
// items that need to be nested
$items = ['<div>A</div>','<div>B</div>','<div>C</div>','<div>D</div>','<div>E</div>','<div>F</div>','<div>G</div>','<div>H</div>','<div>I</div>','<div>J</div>','<div>K</div>'];

$item_count = count($items);
$final_html = '';
$temp_container = [];
$columns = 2;

$i = 0;
$j = 1;
$html_1 = "<div class='columns'>";
$html_2 = "</div>";

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $temp_container[$j] = $item;

    if ($j == $columns OR $i == $item_count-1) {
        $temp_html = '';

        foreach ($temp_container as $temp) {
            $temp_html .= $temp;
        }

        $final_html .= $html_1 . PHP_EOL . $temp_html . $html_2 . PHP_EOL;

        $temp_container = [];
        $j = 0;
    }

    $j++;
    $i++;
}

var_dump($final_html);
```